# How could an AI be programmed, without loopholes, to not kill everyone

Tags: artificial-intelligence

If humans could code an AI, could you easily make some basic rules to 100% know that the AI(s) won't try to exterminate the human race

Comment: What is your work/idea? What have you tried so far and found insufficient? Why?

Comment: Futurama thought about this a lot. The came up with several answers: Make the AI lazy, alcoholic, sex-obsessed, larcenous, and/or easily distracted. They still want to kill all humans, but it's fairly low on the list. More of a talking point at parties.

Comment: An AI will not try to exterminate humanity unless programmed to do so. If you think Siri is up to get you, you should seek medical help.

Comment: Science fiction is a more adequate tag for this question.

Comment: VTC as needing more details. If you want to further explore this topic, I would recommend looking into the 3 laws of robotics and the implications that the laws can clause. Alternatively you would explain how exactly your AI plan to interpret these rules or code. You can imagine that a machine which reads only 1's and 0's is going to have a hard time figuring out what a sentence truly entails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy.  AI (in a general since) involves assigning values to outcomes that tell the AI how important it is to achieve those outcomes, and then letting it experiment with actions which then become positively or negatively reinforced based on how the actions line up with the goals.

To keep AIs from intentionally killing humans, you just need to set the value of not killing humans to exceed all other possible goals combined. This means any experimental behavior that kills a human is guaranteed to be negatively reinforced even if that action meets all of the AIs other desires at once.  While a few mistakes in the early development of the AI may happen, it will be inclined to learn above all things how not to kill people.

Comment: This is *one* view about what an AI is and what an AI does. While it may well be Nosajimiki's view about the a particular field of AI applications, it is not to be taken as any sort of a consensus view, nor as describing all AI applications.

Comment: @AlexP You are right, it does not describe all AI applications and this is a bit of an oversimplification of an entire field of study, but it does describe the vast majority of learning AI applications that are in use or and being developed today.

Comment: I mean... If we’re talking an AGI (the only kind of AI that’s worth worrying about in this scenario) the idea that you’ll have any control over a loss function like this is... pretty laughable. And even if you do all it takes if for the AI to redefine ‘humanity’ to mean ‘a specific subset of people’ and suddenly all kinds of atrocities become viable.

Comment: What is a human? Does arresting everyone into maximally safe containment pods minimize killing humans?

Comment: Human-like learning requires a predefined values that determines our goals: greed, pain-avoidance, laziness, etc.  Yes, systematic desensitization make these goals a moving target which is an important aspect in creating an AGI so that it can handle  task shuffling and exploration, but not killing humans can be made non-desensitizing while other goals desensitize.  Without any priority of goals system, learning is just random static that never goes anywhere.

Comment: @JoeBloggs Don't kill humans and keep humans safe are two different goals.  An "ideal" servant spec for AIs would care very much not to harm humans, but care very little if we harm ourselves.

Comment: I’m not sure why that comment was addressed to me?

Comment: There are all types of loopholes: A AGI powerfull enough to exterminate us is not your avarage atari-playing RL convnet. It may learn that by deliberately not noticing humans dying he can avoid the penalty. Or modify the reward function either in software or hardware. Or readjusts the definition of human (this was already mentioned). Not to mention credit assignment: It may devise such a  convoluted plan to kill a human, that its reward-computing procedures can not determine if it is responsible or not.

Answer (score 0):

### The Three Laws of Robotics.

Originally posited by Isaac Asimov in 1942 as a reason for why the robots in his stories were not xenophobic maniacs like they were usually portrayed at the time, they make *absolutely sure* that a robot can *never* harm a human, with robot brains being programmed in such a way that they immediately self-destruct upon violating them.

Due to their age they are relatively well-known; nevertheless, for those who have been living under a rock their whole lives, here they are:

1. > **A robot may not injure a human being or, through inaction, allow a human being to come to harm.**
2. > **A robot must obey the orders given it by human beings except where such orders would conflict with the First Law.**
3. > **A robot must protect its own existence as long as such protection does not conflict with the First or Second Laws.**

These effectively prevent any robot from harming any human, whether purposefully or on accident.

If you want your robot to be *capable* of harming humans, just not doing so, Asimov solved that problem too. In his novel *Prelude to Foundation*, Asimov stated the so-called "Zeroeth law".

> **0. A robot may not harm humanity as a whole, or, by inaction, allow humanity as a whole to come to harm.**

This overrides the First Law, allowing your robot to harm humans individual humans as long as it is doing so for the general benefit of humanity.

Comment: ...except when the AI's start trying to stop humans from taking *any* risks. Asimov's original work was less cynical than the movie of the same name. (Which offers its own answer: *give the AI empathy*.)

Comment: Most things Asimov wrote that used the three laws also explored various things that can go wrong with it. In one story, robots committed genocide of humans who had taken modifying themselves far enough for robots to not recognise them as human any more.

Comment: @VLAZ Which story? Not that I disagree with you, its just that I don't remember a "robots committing genocide" story. I've read ~95% of the stories and books in Asimov's *Robot* and *Foundation* series (plus the crossovers), and the only ones I remember which are similar are *The Naked Sun* (in which a Solarian scientist tries to get around the Three Laws), and *Foundation and Earth* (some robots have been reprogrammed so that they only think of Solarians as human). Importantly, the robots in these stories are *not* xenophobic; they are merely following orders, following the Second Law.

Comment: Hmm, can't remember the name of the story now. It's been way too long since I've read it. And I can't really find it after searching - there is way too many hits about robots killing humans each of which leads to a rather long article discussing most of Asimov's works. The only one I found that alludes to the story is https://www.brookings.edu/opinions/isaac-asimovs-laws-of-robotics-are-wrong/ where the third paragraph mentions "a story" with genocide but doesn't give a name.

Comment: @VLAZ I believe I know what you are talking about. Although the climax itself is not specifically recounted, one of the main themes in the *Robot* and *Foundation* series is the idea that the Spacers eventually destroyed Earth, as they felt threatened by the second wave of colonization. The robots tried to stop the war, but were unable to do so without violating the First Law. As a result the Zeroeth Law was created; however, the Earth has already been destroyed. The destruction of Earth resulted in retaliatory strikes which also destroyed the Spacer works.